# How to select a row based on values from paired vectors?

Tags: r, filter, subset, combinations

I have a dataframe named `dat` which looks like this:

```
   id1  id2            value
1     3    0 8.00019752415226
2     4    0 27.4861843945884
3     0    3 8.00019752415226
4     4    3 20.1582815171649
5     0    4 27.4861843945884
6     3    4 20.1582815171649
7     1    2                0
8     2    1                0
```

id1 and id2 can take the value of 0 to 4 and are the id numbers of subjects and the value is the euclidean distances between each subject.

Now I have a matrix that I got by taking all the possible combinations of the unique elements of the id variable (basically `c(0,1,2,3,4)`) taken 2 at a time:

```
combn(dat$id,2)
```

which gives the output:

```
>           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
>     [1,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    2    2     3
>     [2,]    1    2    3    4    2    3    4    3    4     4
```

Now I want to select rows in `dat` based on each column of this matrix i.e, select the row with (id1 = 0, id2 = 1); (id1= 0, id2 = 2); (id1 = 0, id2 = 3) and so on and make a dataframe out of them.

Now I can easily implement this with a `for` loop but I am wondering if there is a faster more elegant way to do this with vectorised functions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```r
dat <- read.table(text=
"   id1  id2            value
1     3    0 8.00019752415226
2     4    0 27.4861843945884
3     0    3 8.00019752415226
4     4    3 20.1582815171649
5     0    4 27.4861843945884
6     3    4 20.1582815171649
7     1    2                0
8     2    1                0
", header=TRUE )

look.up <- combn(0:4,2) %>% t %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    setnames( paste0("id",1:2) )

look.up %>% left_join( dat, on=colnames(look.up) )
```

Output:

```
Joining, by = c("id1", "id2")
   id1 id2     value
1    0   1        NA
2    0   2        NA
3    0   3  8.000198
4    0   4 27.486184
5    1   2  0.000000
6    1   3        NA
7    1   4        NA
8    2   3        NA
9    2   4        NA
10   3   4 20.158282
```

Essentially transform the combinations to a 2-column data.frame that matches your data, and perform a `join` where it fetches the value column basd on the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Though your `dat$id` is not available, I created mine with `combn(0:4, 2)` which you can replace with `combn(dat$id, 2)` in the following syntax

```
purrr::map(as.data.frame(combn(0:4, 2)), ~ dat[dat$id1 == .[1] & dat$id2 == .[2],])

$V1
[1] id1   id2   value
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$V2
[1] id1   id2   value
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$V3
  id1 id2    value
3   0   3 8.000198

$V4
  id1 id2    value
5   0   4 27.48618

$V5
  id1 id2 value
7   1   2     0

$V6
[1] id1   id2   value
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$V7
[1] id1   id2   value
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$V8
[1] id1   id2   value
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$V9
[1] id1   id2   value
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$V10
  id1 id2    value
6   3   4 20.15828
```

Above code will work if you want to get each combination as a separate item in a list.  However if you want to combine all these, just use `map_dfr` instead of `map`

```
purrr::map_dfr(as.data.frame(combn(0:4, 2)), ~ dat[dat$id1 == .[1] & dat$id2 == .[2],])

  id1 id2     value
3   0   3  8.000198
5   0   4 27.486184
7   1   2  0.000000
6   3   4 20.158282
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! although your answer is just a single line of code (simpler and more elegant!) it needs a separate package and the other answer seemed more intuitive. Thanks a lot also for introducing me to this package (purr).